# Calculate the total distance between nodes in an ordered array

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

I have a network table with nodes specified by integers in an array, which I have ordered when entering the data. The integers correspond to IDs in a location table, which contains a WKT representation of the points in space. How can I calculate the distance of the network from start to finish?

The simplest case is given below

```
 Network Table
 ---------------
| Nodes         |
 ---------------
| {1,2,3}       |
 ---------------


 Location Table
 ---------------
| ID, Point     |
 ---------------
| 1, (1,0)      |
| 2, (2,0)      |
| 3, (2,1)      |
 ---------------
```

I want to produce the value 2 for the trivial case above. The result should scale to complex networks.

By using ST_distance I can calculate the distance between all the individual points in the network, but I'm struggling to preserve the unique path described by the array.

Comment: What is distance? Is it number of points or distance from the first to the last?

Comment: The distance from first to last, via intermediate nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need [`<->` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html) for PostgreSQL's `point` type (which you *seem* to have):

```
select   network_id, sum(dist)
from     (
  select     n.id network_id, point <-> lag(point) over (partition by n.id order by i) dist
  from       network n
  cross join unnest(nodes) i
  join       location l on l.id = i
) s
group by network_id
```

Or, if you really have geometries & PostGIS, you can use ST_Distance too (although `<->` is [supported by PostGIS too](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html), because it is the general "form" of the distance operator anyway):

```
select   network_id, sum(dist)
from     (
  select     n.id network_id, ST_Distance(point, lag(point) over (partition by n.id order by i)) dist
  from       network n
  cross join unnest(nodes) i
  join       location l on l.id = i
) s
group by network_id
```

http://rextester.com/ESQA1611

Comment: what he really wants is pg routing because it's directional.

Answer (score 1):

```
with network (a) as (values ('{1,2,3}'::int[]))
, location (id, p) as (values (1,'(1,0)'::point),(2,'(2,0)'),(3,'(2,1)'))
select a, sum(dt)
from (
    select
        a,
        abs(p[0] - lag(p[0]) over(partition by a order by id)) +
        abs(p[1] - lag(p[1]) over(partition by a order by id)) as dt
    from
        (
            select a, unnest(a) as id
            from network
        ) network
        inner join
        location using (id)
) s
group by a
;
    a    | sum 
---------+-----
 {1,2,3} |   2
```

With Postgis:

```
with network (a) as (values ('{1,2,3}'::int[]))
, location (id, p) as (values
    (1,st_makepoint(1,0)),(2,st_makepoint(2,0)),(3,st_makepoint(2,1))
)
select a, sum(dt)
from (
    select
        a,
        st_distance(p, lag(p) over(partition by a order by id)) as dt
    from
        (
            select a, unnest(a) as id
            from network
        ) network
        inner join
        location using (id)
) s
group by a
;
    a    | sum 
---------+-----
 {1,2,3} |   2
```